# Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Autofac DLL mismatch when deploying bot to Azure

Tags: botframework

A bot service I'm working on has started receiving 405 Not Allowed messages. I thought it might be because of the default state server being deprecated, so I decided to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to implement in-memory state.

This works well when testing locally against the Bot Framework emulator.  However, when I now deploy the build I get the following error when on the web application entry site:

[image]

Because of security restrictions, I have to deploy by copying files to wwwroot. I've ensured that all old files are deleted, copied in the new ones and restarted the app.

Some of the bindings in Web.config seemed to refer to an older version (3.12.2.4) than what was in the Nuget package manager and so I've updated them as follows before cleaning, rebuilding and re-publishing the app without luck:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.16.1.38846" newVersion="3.16.1.38846" />
```

The following screenshots show the dlls loaded while running locally in VS
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more details about exception than the image you pasted here? 'Cause the details around these assembly binding issues usually include a very deep level of information about what version was being sought after and which one was found that would help diagnose the problem further.

Comment: @DrewMarsh I have updated the question with a more detailed view of the exception :)

Comment: Hmm, ok well... it's clear that you're ending up with the correct versions when running locally, so I'm leaning towards the published version being the problem. Can you expand on what you mean when you say you have to "deploy by copying files to wwwroot"? Can you provide a screenshot/make a diagram showing the files as deployed?

Comment: @DrewMarsh My reason for getting stuck was that we were bogged down by security and having to copy files into the web service folder manually, probably causing all kinds of conflicts along the way. We were eventually able open up a bit and install tools for developing and deploying from Visual Studio.

Thanks for your response and sorry for not getting back to you.